# ITX Case for Zotac ION

Tags: computer-building, mini-itx

Can anyone recomend a resonable case for a Zotac ION ITX board. The heat sink and fan are about 2.25 inches. I originally bought an Apex mi-008 but the fan doesn't clear the PSU. Other than the mobo, I need to get a 3.5 drive in there. No need for an ODD but would consider. Might consider a slim mini atx case. Mostly limited by width in my case next to my TV but the smaller the better.

thanks,

Comment: i just bought the same board and case.  i think you can actually get the fan + PSU in there but it'll be tight.  i'm a little disappointed with the case tho; wish i'd seen this before ordering.

Comment: I actually returned it and went with a Thermaltake sd100. Turned out to be way too loud (psu fan). In the end, I went with a Dell Zino which was back to my original plan. The Zotac was fine. Just wish I could find a case I was really happy with. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the exact same board and I use this case http://www.mini-box.com/M350-universal-mini-itx-enclosure , though I use a 2.5" mobile drive. It's a nice case.

Comment: John T, possibly my bad. I think the height of sink and fan is closer to 2.25 inches. Don't have it with me right now.

Comment: The M350 only has 2.5" drive bays, too :\

Comment: I gave some serious thought to this case but it was out of stock and looked like the entire company was out of town for the week between xmas and the new years.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [Cubid 2755](http://www.mini-itx.com/store/?c=3#2755) is a good fit.

```
Bays: 
1x 2.5in Hard Drive (2.5in-3.5in IDE cable or SATA Data/Powercable required) 
1x 3.5in Hard Drive 
1x slimline Optical Drive (slimline IDE Adapter included) 
2x PCI (right angled dual PCI riser card provided).

Measurements: 63.5(H) x 295(W) x 288(D) mm. (2.5 x 11.6 x 11.3in)
```